# Eruv t'chumin for dependants

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, minor-katan-child, family-members, eruv-techumin

One can 'force' a dependant to make an eruv t'chumin. Since they are only made for a dvar mitsva this is considered like forcing him to do a mitsva which one who has the power, has to do. Normally when one makes an eruv for someone else he provides the food and the other person or someone else lifts it up for him. This is called being 'mzakeh' him. In other words this food now belongs to the other person, since one cannot make an eruv t'chumin using someone else's food only his own. Now my question is when someone makes an eruv for a dependant must he also be m'zakeh him. He has to provide the extra food for him, even if it is a very young child and he cant just be 'added' to his own food. But must he also be m'zake that the food now belongs to the child or can it still belong to him.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29115/can-a-woman-make-an-eiruv-for-her-minor-children

Comment: That is what made me bring up this post.